# How to display the GRUB2 menu from the command line

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-order

I know how to use `sudo grub-set-default #` but I do not know how I can determine what the order is to specify the default boot (without booting and observing the menu).

Is there some way to get grub to echo the menu from the command line?  How can I figure out what 0, 1, 2, etc., are in grub without booting?

Comment: Open `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: You can use description, but must copy & paste exactly. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Specific_Entries

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#A.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-default.2BAC8-grub

find your windows entry in grub.cfg and copy to grub default like this Vista entry - If you edit your windows command use the edited copy as this must match the title exactly:

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and copy title into grub_default  here:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

change to comment # or delete old and add new :

```
#GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows Vista (on /dev/sda1)"
```

Then do:

```
sudo update-grub
```